# Куда автор пушит 5-ку в этом примере?

Tags: javascript, массивы, push

```
var mutableArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.push(5);
console.log(mutableArr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Опечатка?

https://habrahabr.ru/company/devexpress/blog/302118/ (первый пример)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push (mdn ref)

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что опечатка? Вроде всё верно.

Comment: Опечатка, вестимо. Обычное же дело, сначала автор назвал переменную `arr`, потом решил для пущей наглядности переименовать, но по недосмотру переименовал не везде. :)

Comment: Опечатка. Должно быть mutableArr.push(5);